# Как перевести все элементы массива numpy из str в float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Дан массив:

```
а = [['2.51' '2.95' '1' ... '4' '2' '1']
     ['2.29' '3.24' '3' ... '2' '2' '0']
     ['1.72' '5.03' '0' ... '1' '8' '1']]
```

Каким способом можно получить:

```
а = [[2.51 2.95 1. ... 4. 2. 1.]
     [2.29 3.24 3. ... 2. 2. 0.]
     [1.72 5.03 0. ... 1. 8. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходная матрица:

```
In [99]: a
Out[99]:
array([['2.51', '2.95', '1', '4', '2', '1'],
       ['2.29', '3.24', '3', '2', '2', '0'],
       ['1.72', '5.03', '0', '1', '8', '1']], dtype='<U4')
```

Преобразование в тип `float`    :

```
In [100]: a = a.astype("float")
```

результат:

```
In [101]: a
Out[101]:
array([[2.51, 2.95, 1.  , 4.  , 2.  , 1.  ],
       [2.29, 3.24, 3.  , 2.  , 2.  , 0.  ],
       [1.72, 5.03, 0.  , 1.  , 8.  , 1.  ]])

In [102]: a.dtype
Out[102]: dtype('float64')
```